# How do I use Laravel's chunk to avoid running out of memory?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am pulling around 100k records from temporary tables, doing some slight modification on the data, downloading photos, and then putting the fields I need to keep in a "master" table.  This is quickly causing my app to crash as it runs out of memory.

I read the very brief docs on using chunk() with Laravel's eloquent ORM but do not know how to even begin to implement it in my class.

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
    public function fire()
{
    // Turn off query logging
    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

    $feeds = RetsFeed::where('active','=',1)->get();
    foreach ($feeds as $feed)
    {

        $class = "TempListing{$feed->board}";

        $listings = $class::orderBy('MatrixModifiedDT','desc')->get();

        $listings->each(function($listing) use ($feed) {
            ListingMigrator::migrateListing($listing,$feed);
            echo "Feed: $feed->board\r\n";
            echo "SubcondoName: $listing->SubCondoName\r\n";
            echo "Development: $listing->Development\r\n";
            echo "\r\n";
        });
    }

}
```

Each feed (or datasource) is dumped into a temp table in a different chore.  That works fine.  Then, I grab all of hte listings out of one table (which is around 30k on average) and run my ListingMigrator method.

Where do I put the chunk in this example?  Would it replace the line:

```
$listings = $class::orderBy('MatrixModifiedDT','desc')->get();
```

I don't fully understand the closure in the eloquent docs.  This is all they have to say about it and here's the code example from the Laravel site:

```
    User::chunk(200, function($users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `chunk` call should replace the `get` call - it is designed to work on the pre-get() query builder object.

```
$listings = $class::orderBy('MatrixModifiedDT','desc');

$listings->chunk(200, function($listings) use($feed) {
    $listings->each(function($listing) use ($feed) {
        ListingMigrator::migrateListing($listing,$feed);
        echo "Feed: $feed->board\r\n";
        echo "SubcondoName: $listing->SubCondoName\r\n";
        echo "Development: $listing->Development\r\n";
        echo "\r\n";
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work like a charm!  Thanks SO much for your generosity in answering.  My one question though is how we determine the 200 number for the chunk.  My understanding is that it processes that many and then basically "starts over" for lack of a better word.  Wouldn't it be safe ot keep this number really low, like even 10?  Is the only cost of doing that the additional database calls?

Comment: @ChrisFarrugia Chunk size is pretty arbitrary and the only hard requirement is that it's a small enough number so you don't run out of RAM within a single chunk. If your database doesn't mind the load, chunks of 10 are fine. Chunks of 200 are likely also fine.

Comment: Note: if the `chunk` involves modifying records that might affect the query, such as soft deletes, hard deletes, change of column in the query etc, then you need to surround the chunk with a while statement.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700537/eloquent-chunk-missing-half-the-results and possibly http://laravel.io/forum/09-22-2015-chunk-missing-half-the-results?page=1

Comment: I'm running some code with chunks of 2000 entries. My Objects are ~150 bytes after conversion to json. So this generates neat 300KByte chunks, which works well for both my database, the data involved and my PHP memory and runtime limitations.